# Meta's tag pages inaccessible due to self-redirect loop

Tags: bug, tags, meta

Tag pages (route `/questions/tagged/tagname`) redirect to themselves indefinitely:

```
$ curl -D - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/featured
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Location: /questions/tagged/featured
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Date: Fri, 05 Jul 2013 16:47:42 GMT
Content-Length: 143

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="/questions/tagged/featured">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>
```

This only happens on Meta, so far, but only applies to any meta-tag that doesn't have a dash in it; those with a dash seem to be exempt, as do invalid tags:

- [featured](/questions/tagged/featured) redirects.
- [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) does not.
- [adsfdsaf](/questions/tagged/adsfdsaf) does not.

Comment: Wait, this is why I got a "Too many requests from this IP" block earlier today when I tried to look at a meta tag page? Well, that makes sense now.

Comment: Seems like tag pages with a _hyphenated tag_ **don't** self-redirect !?

Comment: @ArneStenström: Good catch! Updated.

Comment: Invalid tags don't redirect either: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/adsfdsaf

Comment: seems to be working now again

Comment: I guess that means it is fixed; perhaps a dev will post and add a `status-` tag.